# DNN rewriting URL and adding Default.aspx? in Query-String

Tags: query-string, dotnetnuke, urlencode

I have a Product list page on DNN.

On this module I have a function which is called when clicked. I am adding the name of the product and SKU in the URL as a Querystring. I noticed that DNN would rewrite ?Title= to /Title/ as well as &SKU= to /SKU/ when the SKU is normal without a forward slash. For example SKU/SR2018B

The URL below would work:
www.ourwebsite.com/Product-View/Title/staple-remover-black/sku/SR2018B

My main problem is when the SKU has a special character like a forward slash, for example: SS023/10. This will cause the URL to break. I am using an encoder for the SKU. Notice that ?Title did not change to /Title/ and now there is a Default.aspx? present in the URL below.

www.ourwebsite.com/Product-View?Title/staples-2313-1000pcs-100-pages/Default.aspx?sku=SS023%2f13

Here is my Code Behind when a person is redirected to the Detailed Page.

```
if (tabIdToRedirectTo == null) m_alerts.ShowModuleMessage(ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType.RedError, $"An error occurred when attempting to Redirect to the '{settingKey}' Page!", ref plcMessages, true); else Response.Redirect(Globals.NavigateURL(tabIdToRedirectTo.TabID, "", "?Title="+ hiddendescription.Value + "&sku=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(hiddensku.Value), EmbeddedModule.GenerateFullQueryStringForEmbedding(EmbeddedCompanyCode, EmbeddedShowCustPricing)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's how you're calling the `Globals.NavigateUrl` function.  The call takes a params of strings which are your query strings in the ***key*=*value*** format.  I usually like to easily see what I am about to pass so I do something like the following:

```
var qsParams = new List<string>{
    "Title=" + hiddendescription.Value, // "Title=staples-2313-1000pcs-100-pages"
    "sku=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(hiddensku.Value), // "sku=SS023%2f13"
    EmbeddedModule.GenerateFullQueryStringForEmbedding(EmbeddedCompanyCode, EmbeddedShowCustPricing)
};

return Globals.NavigateURL(tabIdToRedirectTo.TabID, "", qsParams.ToArray());
```

Granted - I do not know what your `EmbeddedModule.GenerateFullQueryStringForEmbedding` does, but as long as it returns a `key=value` type output, it should be passed and processed well.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion worked. I can now view the Detailed Product Page. The embeddedModule creates a query string which will detect if a Dealer who resells our products has implemented our website in an Iframe on their website and depending if they would like to show pricing it will either hide or show it. It also determines if it must go to another skin page if it is being viewed within an iframe. I must now fix this: http://dnndev.me/Products/Company/003-948/ShowPrices/n?Company=003-948&ShowPrices=n&SkinSrc=[G]%FModern-Skin%fiframe&ProductCategory=6